# How could one prove that b in the GB2 distribution is a scale parameter?

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution, parameterization, gb2

In the Generalized Beta distribution of the second kind (GB2), where a, p, and q are shape parameters and b is a scale parameter, the pdf is defined on $\mathbb{R}_+$ by:
$$
GB2(y;a,b,p,q) = \frac{|a|y^{ap-1}}{b^{ap}B(p,q)(1+(y/b)^a)^{p+q}}
$$

By the definition of a scale parameter, this implies that:
$$
GB2(y;a,b,p,q) = b*GB2(y;a,1,p,q)
$$
And numerical experiments persuade me that this is true of the GB2. However, I can not make the algebra work out. I see a *b* to the negative *ap*, times a *b* to the *a(p + q)*, plus assorted cross-terms. How does that reduce to a *b* to the positive one? Help me out.